# Oil pressure low

Tags: citroen, oil-pressure, citroen-c3

Once every couple of days random I get a warning message stating low oil pressure that comes on and goes of just as quick as you can read it. Any thoughts on what this could be causing this. I drive a citreon c3 10 plate. No lights on dash just oil symbol for a few seconds. Oil level is at the right level.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does a Citroen use an oil pressure sending unit? A plain pressure sensor set to turn on the oil pressure indicator if below a specified value, before startup then turns off after startup. It's possible for sending units to wear out or its wiring becomes intermittent. One way to tell if oil pressure is lower than optimum is to remove the sending unit and put on an oil pressure gauge. You'll need to know minimum oil pressure at idle.

Comment: I have had  low pressure caused by a dirty screen on the oil pump. I fixed it by removing the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens at idle, it's likely that your oil pressure is low.  If oil level is fine main bearing failure is the most likely cause.

There is no way to tell except putting a pressure gauge on the oil line.